# Tier 4 Visa expiring in September 2015. Planning to go Europe in July. Can I apply back at home?

Tags: visas

I'm a Vietnamese and currently studying in the UK. My Tier 4 visa is expiring in September 2015. I booked tickets to Europe for July (which my visa will expires less than 90 days by the end of the trip).

I am planning to go back to Vietnam during summer, and apply for a Schengen Visa there to enter Europe and UK for my graduation in July.

Wondering if this is possible?

Comment: Based upon what you wrote it sounds fine.  Any reason why you think it might not be possible?

Comment: Well, except Schengen visa doesn't let you enter the UK, so you'll need to apply for both a Schengen and a UK Visa.

Answer (score 2):

This depends - when is your study program ending ? 
I studied in the UK for a masters program which ran from September 2011 to August 2012 - I was given a visa which lasted from August 2011 till February 2013 ( i.e 1 month before the program start date and 6 months after the program end date). My graduation ceremony was at the end of January.

I personally did not leave the UK, but quite a few International student friends of mine left the UK for a while, either to to go to their home country or got a schenzen visa to go around Europe. Most of them came back in the UK in time for the graduation ceremony - They used the same old Tier 4 visa.

So what I know I that the Tier 4 visa is designed so that you complete your course and have enough validity so that you can attend your graduation ceremony (or complete any remaining course requirements). It is also a multiple entry visa for the time period it's valid.

tl;dr version-
If your tier 4 visa is valid till when your graduation ceremony is held, then you should have no issues re-entering the UK. Just remember to carry your invitation letter to the ceremony. If you don't have one, ask your university for one.